# MemoryLayout::varHandle Problems with structuring via mutable arrays

Tags: java, project-panama, java-21

When constructing a varHandle using MemoryLayout::varHandle, I passed in a self-assembled Object array to implement the public method for constructing the MemorySegment. However, I find that it seems to prevent me from using Object arrays instead of mutable arrays.

The code snippet is as follows.

```java
public static MemorySegment buildMemorySegment(Object object, MemorySegment memorySegment, MemoryLayout originMemoryLayout, MemoryLayout memoryLayout, List<PathElement> pathElements, List<Object> indexParams) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> aClass = object.getClass();
    if (memoryLayout instanceof SequenceLayout sequenceLayout) {
        pathElements.add(PathElement.sequenceElement());
        for (int i = 0; i < sequenceLayout.elementCount(); i++) {
            Object[] array;
            if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass)) {
                assert object instanceof Collection<?>;
                Collection<?> collection = (Collection<?>) object;
                array = collection.toArray();
            } else {
                assert object instanceof Object[];
                array = ((Object[]) object);
            }
            Object o = array[i];
            indexParams.add((long) i);
            buildMemorySegment(o, memorySegment, originMemoryLayout, sequenceLayout.elementLayout(), pathElements, indexParams);
            indexParams.removeLast();
        }
        pathElements.removeLast();
    } else if (memoryLayout instanceof StructLayout structLayout) {
        List<MemoryLayout> memoryLayouts = structLayout.memberLayouts();
        for (MemoryLayout layout : memoryLayouts) {
            String layoutName = layout.name().orElseThrow();
            pathElements.add(PathElement.groupElement(layoutName));
            Field declaredField = aClass.getDeclaredField(layoutName);
            Object fieldValue = getFieldValue(object, declaredField);
            buildMemorySegment(fieldValue, memorySegment, originMemoryLayout, layout, pathElements, indexParams);
            pathElements.removeLast();
        }
    } else if (memoryLayout instanceof ValueLayout) {
        Object[] varParams = new Object[indexParams.size() + 2];
        varParams[0] = memorySegment;
        for (int i = 0; i < indexParams.size(); i++) {
            varParams[i + 1] = indexParams.get(i);
        }
        varParams[varParams.length - 1] = object;
        VarHandle varHandle = originMemoryLayout.varHandle(pathElements.toArray(new PathElement[0]));
        varHandle.set(varParams);
    }
    return MemorySegment.NULL;
}
```

The key problem is that I successfully built MemoryLayout and constructed varHandle by parsing MemoryLayout to control varHandle parameters. The following problems occur.

[image]

`connot convert MethodHandle(VarHandle,MemorySegment,long,int)void to (VarHandle,Object[])void`

This is what my debug says, and what i want to implement is
`varHandler.set(segment, (long)i, i);`

Can I implement my idea? How do I do it?

Comment: I suppose you seeing a `WrongMethodTypeException`?

Comment: Yes, I see that. What can I do to meet my expectations?

Comment: If the c function returns an array pointer, I have to know its length in advance in java. If I don't know the length is not able to serialize the memory segment to the java entity

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual output like that exception stacktrace. Please post the stacktrace as code-formatted **text**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not pass an `Object[]` holding the coordinates, directly to `VarHandle::set` (because it is a [signature polymorphic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#sigpoly) method).

However, you can convert the var handle to a method handle using `toMethodHandle` and then use `invokeWithArguments`:

```
MethodHandle setter = varHandle.toMethodHandle(VarHandle.AccessMode.SET);
setter.invokeWithArguments(varParams);
```